# Как узнать высоту обьекта их xml файла в MainActivity

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: необходимо узнать высоту картинки (обьекта) их xml файла. В xml есть строчка, которая задает высоту этой картинке. `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"`. А мне нужно эти 0.4 преобразовать в px. При том нужно чтобы на разных экранах число px было разное.
Помогите плиз.

Answer (score 0):

Это должно помочь

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout); 
final ViewTreeObserver observer= layout.getViewTreeObserver();
 observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener( new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        Log.d("Log", "Height: " + layout.getHeight()); 
    }
});
```